# Cannot resolve commons-collections:commons-collections:2.1

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, pom.xml

I have an issue when i try to fix my code. I keep getting issue when I reload maven/reimport maven
Cannot resolve `commons-collections:commons-collections:2.1`

When I open Maven I see in the folder in Dependencies an error starts in `commons-validator:commons-validator:1.3.1`

Here my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath />
        <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demoSpring</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demoSpring</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-validation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.assertj/assertj-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.16.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>demoSpring</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

take a look and see how I can fix this.

```
Cannot resolve commons-collections:commons-collections:2.1

Cannot resolve org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.4

Cannot resolve commons-digester:commons-digester:1.6

Cannot resolve xml-apis:xml-apis:1.0.b2

Cannot resolve commons-logging:commons-logging:1.0.4
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is "Cannot resolve commons-collections:commons-collections:2.1"

It has nothing to do with "commons-validator" dependency.

The commons collection artifact has moved to a different location in maven artifactory.

Please check this out
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-collections4

Comment: Im getting an error when I added`<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-collections4 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
    <version>4.4</version>
</dependency>`
The error Im getting is commons-collections4 is not found in dependency

Comment: Please update/clean project . If you are using eclipse, maven-> update project -> force update

Comment: Im using Intellij

Answer (score 0):

try to change version of your package, but better find dependency in https://mvnrepository.com/ which you need, copy this text and try to reimport.